# Tailwinds tailwind.config.js content property

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to understand how the **tailwind.config.js** file works.
I have a simple **index.html** file with tailwinds classes, and it works! But I don't understand how is it possible, because the content attribute from the **tailwind.config.js** is looking inside the ./src folder for the html templates, right?

```
module.exports = {
  
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],

  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ["Graphik", "sans-serif"],
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        midnight: "#121063",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

For some reason it reads/detect the files in the root as well (outside the src folder), is there any reason for this? Thanks.

Project stucture

```
node_modules
index.html
package.json
tailwind.config.js
postcss.config
vite.config
src/
   css/
   js/
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you are already using postcss. Here you define input CSS file and output file. The tailwindcss config file configures other things. With commands like for example: npm run build you build your application. Here the config files give the instructions on what to do.

Of course, you then use the output css in your index.html!

You can also just build the tailwindcss output file with an npx command.
`npx tailwindcss -c ./tailwindcss-config.js -i input.css -o output.css`

Comment: Ok thank for your answer, but I still not understanding, what is the   content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
 for?

Comment: @R0bertinski `["./src/**/*.{html,js}"]`, This means that Tailwind will only go through html and javascript files in the /src folder when building to see which styles are used. From this tailwind generates your new CSS file with only the styles you really use. This process is also called purgen.

Comment: That's why I don't understand, because the index.html it is not in the src folder, but when I change some class in the index.html file, the css is updated. I am not sure if I am explaining correct myself.

Comment: @R0bertinski I think you have a little problem understanding tailwind. More questions: 1) How do you trigger the build of tailwind? 2) how big is your output tailwind styles file? 3) Can you please include your package.json in your question?

Comment: In my understanding, tailwind scans the html sources and traspile (or transform) to css classes, right? But as I mentioned above, the file is not in the folder I've configurated in the tailwind.config.js file. The build is trigger with a "npm run dev"  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },  I am using vite as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind CSS works by scanning all HTML, JavaScript, and any other template files for class names, then generating all the corresponding CSS for those styles.

Consequently, the path `./src/**/*.{html,js}` you defined in content means that any directory after src that contains html and js files of any name doesn't matter , TilwindCSS checks them.

- Use `*` to match anything except slashes and hidden files
- Use `**` to match zero or more directories
- Use comma separate values between `{}` to match against a list of options

For more information, refer to the following link:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

I hope I was able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely right. Tailwind should not be scanning your index.html. It should only be scanning the listed file in the content array. My guess is you might have missed something. May be you followed the installation guide and mistakely compiled and linked the output file to your index.html.